# $y\mapsto 10^y$ Bijection between integers and powers of 10

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Say $y$ and $x \in \mathbb N$

such that $10^y = x$

MSE research gives me this: $y\mapsto 10^y$

For some of you to see the bijection between the integers and powers of 10 will be obvious, but I really can't find a way to show it formally. I'm aware this is related to other questions on MSE but I'm pretty desperate.

The only thing I can think of is that every power of ten maps to a decimal...or something :/

Normally this is the part where I would insert what I have tried - but after hours of trawling the internet I'm afraid I've learned very little.

*Looking for a bijection (or just injection?) to show it is countably infinite.*

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Hint? Do you know how to prove there's a bijection between natural numbers and even natural numbers? If so, can you modify it to answer your question?

Comment: Your question seems muddled.  What is the formal statement that you are trying to show formally?  What is it that you believe you need to do in order to solve this problem?

Comment: A natural number, $x$, is called a power of ten if there exists another natural number, $y$,
such that $10^y = x$. Show that the set of powers of ten is countably infinite.
That is the actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to prove that the function is *injective*.

Now, "the powers of 10" needs to be defined. The most natural definition of that phrase is actually that "powers of 10" means *the range of the function you have just defined*.

Then you just need to appeal to the general fact that an injective function is a bijection onto its range.

---

Why is it injective? That depends on what definition you have for $10^y$, but if we assume a recursive definition along the lines of
$$ 10^0 = 1 \\ 10^{n+1} = 10^n\cdot 10 $$

then you can prove by induction on $n$ that $10^n\ge 1$ and then by induction on $k$ that $10^n < 10^{n+k+1}$.

In particular, if you have $a\ne b$ then either $a=b+k+1$ for some $k$ or $b=a+k+1$ for some $k$, and the second induction now shows that $10^a\ne 10^b$.

Comment: I know you're not meant to comment "thanks." But you went out if your way and it will help me a lot. So in this sense, using induction sort of shows that there is 1:1 mapping? I've only ever used induction to prove statements. So it's telling us (these inductions) that there is no more than one element in the domain, that maps to an element in the co domain?